# How do I add newlines between lines printed on the command line?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, logs, output, text-formatting

Mail logs are incredibly difficult to read. How could I output a blank line between each line printed on the command line? For example, say I'm grep-ing the log. That way, multiple wrapped lines aren't being confused.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
sed G 
# option: g G    Copy/append hold space to pattern space.
```

`G` is not often used, but is nice for this purpose. *sed* maintains two buffer spaces: the “pattern space” and the “hold space”. The lines processed by *sed* usually flow through the pattern space as various commands operate on its contents (`s///`, `p`, etc.); the hold space starts out empty and is only used by some commands.

The `G` command appends a newline and the contents of the hold space to the pattern space. The above *sed* program never puts anything in the hold space, so `G` effectively appends just a newline to every line that is processed.

Comment: The -e isn't necessary. piping `whatever | sed G` ought to do the trick.

Comment: @frabjous: Right, might as well leave off the `-e` since there we only need a single command argument.

Comment: Can I give you like, +2? Nails it!

Comment: but, it is only show in stdout, but not save it

Answer (score 10):

Use awk to add an extra newline.  This also lets you filter out things you don't want.

```
awk '{print $0,"\n"}' | less
```

Answer (score 7):

Use sed and replace the whole line by itself plus one extra newline character:

```
grep foo /var/log/maillog | sed -e "s/^.*$/&1\n/"
```

Comment: A slightly simpler sed substitution would be 's/$/\n/', although @Chris Johnsen's 'G' command is even simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

`grep SPAM  mail.log | while read -r line; do echo; echo $line; done`

Comment: You will probably want to use `read -r` to avoid treating backslash characters as special.

Answer (score 3):

#### Pipe `|` any output to:

```
sed G
```

#### Example:

```
ls | sed G
```

#### If you `man sed` you will see

`G` Append's a newline character followed by the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for more than just have look, I prefer to send them to a text file and open with a text editor so you can set the lines to wrap or not and do searches easily...
and delete the unwanted lines and so on without having to type a lot of commands.

`cat file.log > log.txt`
and `gedit log.txt` or a terminal editor like nano

Edit: or `cp file.log log.txt` wich is of course easier and faster... thanks to KeithB comment

Comment: Why `cat` and not `cp`?

Comment: sure `cp` would be easier and faster!... lol - I was reading the other answers dealing with `grep` and `awk` so I wrote it the `cat` way but I'm correcting that, thanks