# Insert a blank line before a text with sed

Tags: sed

Referring to this discussion [how-do-i-add-newlines-between-lines-printed-on-the-command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-add-newlines-between-lines-printed-on-the-command-line?newreg=8bc076352d4d4c57b533d351e42d4fef), I need to insert a blank line before a text. I've:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
# Set TexLive 2017 PATH
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH \
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH \
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH' .bashrc
```

but I'd like to have a new blank line before

```
# Set TexLive 2017 PATH
```

How can I put it? Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your command is broken altogether because you need a `\` after `# Set TexLive 2017 PATH` but to add a newline as well try this:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
\
# Set TexLive 2017 PATH \
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH \
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH \
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH' .bashrc
```